# How to set attributes of onPendingTransition() animation programmatically

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

Can i set the xml atrributes of this animation for onPendingTransition() programmatically?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:zAdjustment="top">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="83%"
        android:duration="400"
        />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call [`overridePendingTransition(R.anim.yourEnterAnim, R.anim.yourExitAnim)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int))